# Bootstrap grid with different height columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a grid working for video thumbnails. I want there to be 4 columns on desktop, and 2 columns on tablet/mobile.

Each column contains a thumbnail and the title of the video. The problem is that some of the video titles are longer than others, causing the grid to become messed up. I just want to make it so that the columns can be any height and the number of columns per row won't get messed up from the floating.

I read another answer on this site, but it is not working for me at all.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 index-col">
      <div class="well">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="http://localhost/me/loldie/images/thumbnails/gas-station-safety-19.jpg" alt="Gas station safety" class="img-responsive">
         Gas station safety             
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 index-col">
      <div class="well">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="http://localhost/me/loldie/images/thumbnails/wild-squirrels-love-sunflower-seeds-17.jpg" alt="Wild squirrels love sunflower seeds" class="img-responsive">
         Wild squirrels love sunflower seeds                
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 index-col">
      <div class="well">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="http://localhost/me/loldie/images/thumbnails/bobcats-fighting-in-tree-22.jpg" alt="Bobcats fighting in tree" class="img-responsive">
         Bobcats fighting in tree               
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 index-col">
      <div class="well">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="http://localhost/me/loldie/images/thumbnails/head-on-train-crash-20.jpg" alt="Head on train crash" class="img-responsive">
         Head on train crash                
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 index-col">
      <div class="well">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="http://localhost/me/loldie/images/thumbnails/spelling-pregnant-is-hard-2.jpg" alt="Spelling pregnant is hard" class="img-responsive">
         Spelling pregnant is hard              
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 index-col">
      <div class="well">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="http://localhost/me/loldie/images/thumbnails/kid-rolls-car-while-singing-1.jpg" alt="Kid rolls car while singing" class="img-responsive">
         Kid rolls car while singing                
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 index-col">
      <div class="well">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="http://localhost/me/loldie/images/thumbnails/usa-unemployment-map-timeline-6.jpg" alt="USA unemployment map timeline" class="img-responsive">
         USA unemployment map timeline              
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 index-col">
      <div class="well">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="http://localhost/me/loldie/images/thumbnails/guy-trolls-car-dealership-5.jpg" alt="Guy trolls car dealership" class="img-responsive">
         Guy trolls car dealership              
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 index-col">
      <div class="well">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="http://localhost/me/loldie/images/thumbnails/red-dead-redemption-2-trailer-9.jpg" alt="Red Dead Redemption 2 Trailer" class="img-responsive">
         Red Dead Redemption 2 Trailer              
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 index-col">
      <div class="well">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="http://localhost/me/loldie/images/thumbnails/nintendo-switch-preview-7.jpg" alt="Nintendo Switch preview" class="img-responsive">
         Nintendo Switch preview                
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 index-col">
      <div class="well">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="http://localhost/me/loldie/images/thumbnails/you-re-dying-12.jpg" alt="You're dying" class="img-responsive">
         You're dying               
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 index-col">
      <div class="well">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="http://localhost/me/loldie/images/thumbnails/university-goalie-signed-by-canucks-10.jpg" alt="University goalie signed by Canucks" class="img-responsive">
         University goalie signed by Canucks                
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
.index-col a {
    display: block;
}
.index-col a img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .index-col:nth-child(2n) {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .index-col:nth-child(2n)::after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        clear: both;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .index-col:nth-child(4n) {
        border: 1px solid green;
    }

    .index-col:nth-child(4n)::after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

The problem is with the ::after code. It doesn't seem to be clearing the float at all. It has no effect whatsoever.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the columns to be the same height? Or do you want more of a _masonry_ effect?

Comment: i dont want them to be the same height or have a masonry effect. i simply want them to be 4 columns on desktop, 2 columns on mobile, regardless of their heights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `clear: both` to the first element in the next row instead of the `::after` pseudo-element of the last element in the row.

```
.index-col a {
    display: block;
}
.index-col a img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.index-col:nth-child(4n+1) {
        clear: both;
    }

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .index-col:nth-child(2n) {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .index-col:nth-child(2n+1) {
        clear: both;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .index-col:nth-child(4n) {
        border: 1px solid green;
    }

    .index-col:nth-child(4n+1) {
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vncc1qqh/) you have a working example

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much.